# Changing Time Type for Postgres In Python

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime-format

I have times from a table that take this form:

```
2017-12-31T23:59:59.8560818Z
```

I'm not entirely sure what form this actually is. All I know is that I want to convert it in python to a type of time that is acceptable to insert into a postgres table as a timestamp or date (I really only care about the date). Any ideas for a better way to do this than just taking a substring of the date?

When I try this:

```
exchange_rate['time'] = str(exchange_rate['time'])[:10]  #captures the YYY-MM-DD from date
exchange_rate['time'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(exchange_rate['time'], '%Y-%m-%d') #converts to datetime

cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO bitcoin VALUES ({},{})'''.format(exchange_rate['time'],exchange_rate['rate']))
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Date literals in postgresql must be quoted. (with single quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Date-literals should be quotes (otherwise the tokenizer would get confused...)
- if you want to chop off the fractional seconds, [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) could be used.

---

```
CREATE TABLE bogus
        ( id integer PRIMARY KEY
        , ztimestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
        );
INSERT INTO bogus(id,ztimestamp) VALUES
 ( 1, '2017-12-31T23:59:59.8560818Z')
,( 2, DATE_TRUNC('sec', '2017-12-31T23:59:59.8560818Z'::timestamp))
        ;

SELECT * FROM bogus;
```

---

RESULT:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 2
 id |          ztimestamp           
----+-------------------------------
  1 | 2018-01-01 00:59:59.856082+01
  2 | 2017-12-31 23:59:59+01
(2 rows)
```